# How to sanitize $_POST for wordpress WP_QUERY?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

Anyone know how to sanitize the `$_POST` for wordpress? Or is it already sanitized when i used the `WP_QUERY`? thanks!

I was thinking whether i use `mysql_escape()` or `esc_sql()` [wordpress function].

```
function checkIfEmailAndPasswordHaveUser( $email, $password ) {   

$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'my_custom_post_type',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'     => 'email',
            'value'   => $email
        ),
        array(
            'key'       => 'password',
            'value'     => $password
        ),
    ),
);

$query = new WP_Query( $args );
    if( !$query->have_posts() ) {
        return false;
    } else {
        // return the user's ID
        return $query->posts[0]->ID;
    }
}

$post_user_email        = trim( $_POST['user_email'] );
$post_user_password     = trim( $_POST['user_password'] );

// check if user_id exist
$result = checkIfEmailAndPasswordHaveUser($post_user_email, $post_user_password);
```

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Validating_Sanitizing_and_Escaping_User_Data

Comment: WP sanitizes it for you.

Comment: seems like those are the functions to prevent XSS attacks. I was hoping something to prevent SQL injections. What i meant with the question is, do i have to mysql_escape it when i use WP_QUERY or ACF functions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

turns out WP sanitizes it automatically.